# Can we say that $E[u_i|X_i] \neq 0$ if $Cov(X,u) \neq 0$?

Tags: covariance, conditional-expectation

I'm looking for a proof, if there is one, which links any relationship (if any) between the covariance of two variables and its conditional expectation. This is part of a larger question regarding a linear regression model that deals with discrete variables. Thanks

EDIT:
The context is as follows:

$u_i$ and $X_i$ are the error term and regressor, respectively, in the linear model for the variable $Y_i=\alpha+\beta_1X_i+U_i.$ Additionally, the question provides that $Cov(u_i, X_i)\neq0$, but makes no assumptions re. $E[u_i]$.

Comment: Please explain your notation, because it is ambiguous and is susceptible to several reasonable but differing interpretations in this context: how are $u_i$ and $X_i$ related to $u$ and $X$?  What kinds of random variables are $X$ and $u$?

Comment: @whuber ok, I've added an edit to the question

Comment: I would guess you are also assuming $\operatorname{Cov}(U_i,X_i)=0$ and $E[U_i]=0.$ In that case you can relate the covariance to the conditional expectation via $$\operatorname{Cov}(U_i,X_i)=E[U_iX_i]=E[E[U_i\mid X_i]].$$

Comment: @whuber the question actually assumes that $Cov(u_i, X_i)\neq0$, but makes no assumptions re. $E[u_i]$ afaik. I've also added this update to the question.

Comment: Without an assumption on $E[U_i],$ there is no basis to refer to it as an "error" term.

Comment: fair point. I will have to check the question's assumptions list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Note that if $E(U | X ) = 0$, then

$$ E(U) = E( E (U | X ) ) = 0$$ and $$E(XU) = E(X E(U | X)) = 0$$.

Since $Cov(X, U) = E(XU) - E(X)E(U)$, we get that

$$Cov(X,U) \not = 0 \implies E(U|X) \not =  0.$$

Comment: how can one show that $E(XU)=E(XE(U|X))$? this is coincidentally another equation that I've been trying to understand as well

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation